# include a repository in a pull request in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

How do I include a repository in a pull request? I am trying to add the repository "mwc" in my pull request on the repository "mwc_j"

[image]
[image]

Comment: to clarify: I want the repository "mwc" to be the master of the repository "mwc_j" so that i could create a pull request.

Comment: Where are your changes? When you say "master", you mean mwc is the destination or source?

Comment: I created mwc_j by cloning mwc. I would also like the mwc user to get my pull requests from mwc_j. I guess mwc is both the source and destination.

Comment: Was it cloned or forked? If you want to contribute back to the original repo(mwc in your case), it is better to follow Fork, Branch & PR workflow. Refer https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow for details. You push your changes to your "fork" (mwc_j in your case) and then create a PR from mwc_j to mwc. It is good to use "feature" branch (just create a branch with name that describes your changes, like oauth2_support) instead of using master branch. I could not find an intuitive UI for forking on Bitbucket website. On Github, it is very intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Fork the repo (mwc in your case). It is creating a copy of original repo under your account. BB let's you rename the repo at this step. Assume you chose mwc_j. As I said, it is not so intuitive in BB when compared to GH.

Refer https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html.

2) Clone your repo (mwc_j) to your computer.

Use command like `git clone https://JeremiahCanuto@bitbucket.org/JeremiahCanuto/mwc_j.git`

3) In your computer navigate to git repo directory and create a branch for your changes using command like `git checkout -b oauth2_support`. ***In your case, you have directly used master branch to make changes. But it is good practice to create a topic branch.***

4) Now you can make changes to the source, commit and push to your repo (mwc_j) using a command like `git push  origin --set-upstream oauth2_support`

5) After successfully completing this step, you will see a new branch in the BB website under your repo (mwc_j) but not in mwc yet.

6) Now create a Pull Request by following instructions @ https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-pull-request-to-merge-your-change-774243413.html.

This is where you have trouble I guess.

On the left side you see your repo (mwc_j) and branch (oauth2_support). All your changes are in this branch now.

And on the right side you will have `mwc` repo and `master` branch by default, but you can use the drop down to change destination to `mwc_j` and `master` branch.

However, based on your description you would want to leave it as `mwc` & `master` so that your changes will be merged to `mwc` repo and others will get your changes.

It is possible to keep your changes separate in `oauth2_support` branch in `mwc` by selecting `mwc` from repo drop down and `oauth2_support(new branch)` option for branch name drop down. In this case your changes won't be merged to mwc master branch.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your `mwc_j` repo, you can add another remote using command

```
git remote add mwc <Your mwc git url>
```

then

```
git push mwc <your_local_branch>:<your_mwc_branch>
```

Note: `origin` is an alias for a remote you can add any number of remote.